# Drupal - Why 'FROM node node' in the SQL query in Views?

Tags: sql, drupal

OK... I'm delving into the bowels of Drupal in an effort to understand just what the hell is going on in there :)

I'm sure this is a ridiculously silly question, but when I create a node view why is the SQL query 'SELECT [....] FROM node node' and not just 'SELECT [....] FROM node' What does the second 'node' signify?

Cheers,
James

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"node node" is the table alias, which happens to be identical to the real table name in your query. Aliases are used for [JOIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html) statements.

> A table reference can be aliased using tbl_name AS alias_name or tbl_name alias_name:

I am guessing that drupal generates the alias even when it is not needed.

Comment: The explicit reason is most likely that Drupal supports a database table prefix, so node could on another install actually be something like drupal_node. And to be able to always identify that table, views adds an alias.

Answer (score 1):

As brian_d says, the second occurrence of `node` is the table's alias for use in the query.  It might be (though I don't know for sure) that the alias is generated as a sanitized identifier in case the actual table name is something unwieldy like `Star$Linked_System:username:password@example.com:3306:/some/insane;filesystem`.

For a nice name like `node`, the sanitized version is the same as the original.